# CSS - Add Color with a data attribute - attr(data-color color)

Tags: html, css, less, twig

I'm trying to add color to different element with a data attribute in my css but doensn't work ...

I follow this instructions :

[The attr() Function: Properties Values Collected from the Edited Document.](http://oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-oxygen/index.html#topics/dg-attr-function.html)

[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="bgborder" data-color="#e7663f"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Blaablaaablaaa</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="bgborder" data-color="#77c385"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Blablaablaaa</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.bgborder {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: attr(data-color color);
}
```

Nothing appears...Am I right ?

In my chrome inspector I have this :

```
background-color: attr(data-color color); 
/!\ Invalid property value
```

I don't understand why... ???

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Always a good idea to read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr

[image: screenshot of support table]

Surprise! If nothing supports it, then it won't work ;)

Alternative: If you know you only have a limited range of colours, try:

```
[data-color=red] {background-color:red !important}
[data-color=blue] {background-color:blue !important}
[data-color=zophan-blue] {background-color:#33ccff !important}
```

As you can see, this allows flexibility, such as defining your own colours ;)

Comment: s***... it's to bad... no other possibility to do that ? with less ? (but without jquery)

Comment: You mean other than `style="background-color:#123456;"`?

Comment: @Zagloo: With Less you can use loops to avoid repetition of code but the compiled CSS would still have to be the same way as mentioned above.

Comment: 3 years later, still no support :p

Comment: Same it still doesnt support , sad when we have to theme the sites dynamically!

Comment: how about now? :-)

Comment: The time has come to 2022, attr still only supports string format...

Answer (score 77):

You can pass css values from html:

```
<button style="
    --tooltip-string: 'Ug. Tooltips.';
    --tooltip-color: #f06d06;
    --tooltip-font-size: 11px;
    --tooltip-top: -10px">
  Button
</button>
```

to css:

```
button::after {
  content: var(--tooltip-string);
  color: var(--tooltip-color);
  font-size: var(--tooltip-font-size);
}
```

source: https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/
codepen: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EbxVME

Comment: Neat solution, here is browser support for that https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20v

Comment: This is great. The var is inherited by child elements too which is extra-awesome!

Comment: You make my day!

Comment: Beautiful hack. Quite elegant way around the lack of attr support!

Answer (score 30):

If you are talking only about colors, you can use currentColor value as a proxy.

For example:

HTML

```
<td>
   <span class="bgborder" style="color: #e7663f"></span>
   <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
</td>
```

CSS

```
.bgborder {
  background-color: currentColor;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the CSS `attr` function can only be used with the `content` property in browsers

**[See here for compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility)**

Per the CSS2 spec:

> Limited to the content property

CSS3 will extend this (proposal)

> ..can be used on all properties; may return other values than
>   `<string>`

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you are looking is [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/var) and you can use at Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Check the browser support at [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20v)

And can see more at the video from [Lea Verou](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZOJCVvyF-4&t=1730s)

Answer (score 2):

alternately a very handy bit of javascript:

```
<P _my_colour="red" >one</P>
<P _my_colour="blue">two</P>
<P _my_colour="green">three</P>
<script>
    var my_col = document.querySelectorAll("[_my_colour]");
      my_col.forEach(element => {
        element.style.color = element.getAttribute("_my_colour");
    })

</script>
```

The css solutions outlined by other contributors are generally better and simpler, so a JS solution is somewhat reinventing the wheel, but does do explicitly what you want in the question, so it's here for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, it's always possible!. Example:
Let's define a global variable in css:

```
:root {
  --theglobalvariable: coral;
}
```

In Javascript:
Let's modify that global variable from javascript, assigning as value, the content of an element's attribute

```
var root = document.querySelector(':root');
root.style.setProperty('--theglobalvariable', document.getElementById('IdElement').getAttribute('NameOfAttribute'));
```

Now, in Css let's insert the value of the global variable into the element we want, and enjoy!

```
.someElement{
    color:var(--theglobalvariable);
}
```