# Dynamically provide values to CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, less

I am trying to set color of a div dynamically.

To give an overview of issue, let's check below things:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="shape" id="shape1"></div>
    <div class="shape" id="shape2"></div>
    <div class="shape" id="shape3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the CSS I am using:

```
.shape {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #dfd;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Is it possible that I can give `class="shape-fdd"` in html then it show light red color, if I give `class="shape-dfd"` then it show light green color?

I have just looked into LESS for the same but I don't know if it can provide this feature.

I don't look for jQuery solutions for this. Only CSS or with LESS or SASS if possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not have a class of red and light green ready and just add or remove that class depending on situation?

Comment: I can do that but i don't want to.

Comment: If you could update you question showing all the classes you write about. Neither `shape-fdd` nor `dfd` is in your question so it is very difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking here? Elaborate more.

Comment: What would trigger the dynamic part? Or do you just want to have them to have different colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Edited]** since my answer has been accepted:
I just want to highlight for later readers that **the following won't work for now: this is not yet possible in css3 (only supported for content attribute right now)** :)

Just a quick note for info.
It is not yet possible in css3 (only for content attribute right now) but maybe soon:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="shape" id="shape1" data-color="#fdd"></div>
    <div class="shape" id="shape2" data-color="#fdd"></div>
    <div class="shape" id="shape3" data-color="#fdd"></div>
</body>
</html>


.shape {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: attr(data-color);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Can check on [CSS - Add Color with a data attribute - attr(data-color color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529374/css-add-color-with-a-data-attribute-attrdata-color-color)

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery and two different class you can achieve like this

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="shape-dfd" id="shape1"></div>
    <div class="shape-dfd" id="shape2"></div>
    <div class="shape-dfd" id="shape3"></div>
    <input type="button" id="classDfd" value="Add dfd class" />
    <input type="button" id="classFdd" value="Add fdd class" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Style**

```
.shape-dfd {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #dfd;
  margin: 20px;
}
.shape-fdd {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fdd;
  margin: 20px;
}
</style>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#classDfd").click(function(){

       $("div[id^='shape']").removeClass("shape-fdd");
       $("div[id^='shape']").addClass("shape-dfd");
   });

   $("#classFdd").click(function(){

       $("div[id^='shape']").removeClass("shape-dfd");
       $("div[id^='shape']").addClass("shape-fdd");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class on your css and use it in your html.

```
.dfd {
    background: #dfd;
}
```

Then `class="shape dfd"` to apply the color of the `.shape` class.

Here's a working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kou75mLo/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you would like to set it dynamically, javascript/jQuery?
I would start with this. Setting the colors in data-attributes and specifying them in your css, or just do plain classes depending on requirements of the dynamic part.

Something like

```
[data-color="blue"] {
  background-color: deepskyblue !important;
}

[data-color="red"] {
  background-color: tomato !important;
}
```

and your html would look like

```
<div class="shape" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="shape" data-color="red"></div>
```

[demo found at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm8pubqe/3/)

**EDIT**
If I got you right you want this. You would have to do a mixin or extend in SCSS (check syntax for LESS, jsfiddle only support SCSS hence I use it). You do a base class and then extend that with the color once, like this

```
   .shape {
        background-color: aqua;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .shape-blue {
        @extend .shape;
        background-color: deepskyblue;
    }

    .shape-red {
        @extend .shape;
        background-color: tomato;
    }
```

[demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm8pubqe/4/)