# Access pseudo class element attribute width from scss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I'm trying to change width and height of pseudo-class element through the attribute. I'm doing this because I cannot change pseudo element in javascript. What's wrong in my code? Mozilla says its posible:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Examples

```
.loader::before {
height: 30px;
width: attr(data-width);
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
content: '';}
```

javascript:

```
$('.loader').attr('data-width', '100px');});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9j2pbbzd/

Comment: _“Mozilla says its posible”_ - scroll down to the Browser compatibility section ...

Comment: Ok, I missed it. Thx

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/wp7Wc/4/ this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, at the moment you can use `attr()` just into `content` property. Look at this similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27529435/1849721

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a class with the width/height you want the pseudo element to have and use JS to add/remove this classes as you want to ?