# how to define HTML custom attribute taking multiple values just like class attribute?

Tags: html, css, class, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I want to know if I am able to define a custom HTML attribute that can take 2 or more values just as the 'CLASS" attribute.
For instance, considering I define a "Data-Text" and in css I write:

```css
[data-text=light]{color:white;}
[data-text=bold]{font-weight:bolder;}
```

Now, can I make a trick that if I write :

```html
<p data-text = "light bold"> something </p>
```

both commands (font-weight and color) happen for the `<p>` tag?

Comment: try this visit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529374/css-add-color-with-a-data-attribute-attrdata-color-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible when you use the css "~="

```
[data-text~=light]{color:white;} [data-text~=bold]{font-weight:bolder;}
```

this should work just fine.